# How to import nodeViewProps object from TipTap in Vue 3 script setup?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, tiptap, vue-script-setup

I'm using `TipTap`, a `Rich Text Editor` and the way they handle props in vue components (composition api) is by importing them like so:

```
<script>
import { nodeViewProps } from '@tiptap/vue-3'

export default {

  props: nodeViewProps

}

</script>
```

logging `nodeViewProps` shows an `object of objects`:

```
{0: false, 1: true, editor: {…}, node: {…}, decorations: {…}, selected: {…}, extension: {…}, …}
  0: false
  1: true
  decorations: {required: true, type: ƒ}
  deleteNode: {required: true, type: ƒ}
  editor: {required: true, type: ƒ}
  extension: {required: true, type: ƒ}
  getPos: {required: true, type: ƒ}
  node: {required: true, type: ƒ}
  selected: {required: true, type: ƒ}
  updateAttributes: {required: true, type: ƒ}
  [[Prototype]]: Object
```

How would I import this `prop object` inside of `script setup`? I've tried:

```
<script setup>
import {nodeViewProps} from '@tiptap/vue-3'

const props = defineProps([
    nodeViewProps
])

const props = defineProps([
    'nodeViewProps'
])

const props = defineProps({
    nodeViewProps: nodeViewProps
})

const props = defineProps({
    node: nodeViewProps
})

</script>
```

none of which seems to be the correct way.

```
console.log(props.nodeViewProps)
```

outputs `undefined`.

Comment: props are passed in on component attributes ... `<your-component something="somevalue">` ... so, not sure what you're even trying to do in your code

Comment: @Bravo Yes, that's how it usually works but `TipTap` seems to do it differently by importing a `prop object` and somehow using it in the props directly. Or I am overlooking something. No prop is passed to the mentioned `vue component`.

Comment: I doubt tiptap changes how vue works - you probably don't understand tiptap documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it works in `script setup`. Apparently you don't need to import `nodeViewProps` anymore and instead a `node` prop object is passed by default to your `vue component` which can be accessed like so:

```
<script setup>
import {NodeViewWrapper} from '@tiptap/vue-3'


const props = defineProps({
    node: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    },
    updateAttributes: {
        type: Function,
        required: true,
    }
})

const increase = () => {
    props.updateAttributes({
        count: props.node.attrs.count + 1,
    })
}
</script>
```

This component if from their [documentation](https://tiptap.dev/guide/node-views/vue) and its original form looks like this:

```
<template>
  <node-view-wrapper class="vue-component">
    <span class="label">Vue Component</span>

    <div class="content">
      <button @click="increase">
        This button has been clicked {{ node.attrs.count }} times.
      </button>
    </div>
  </node-view-wrapper>
</template>

<script>
import { NodeViewWrapper, nodeViewProps } from '@tiptap/vue-3'

export default {
  components: {
    NodeViewWrapper,
  },

  props: nodeViewProps,

  methods: {
    increase() {
      this.updateAttributes({
        count: this.node.attrs.count + 1,
      })
    },
  },
}
</script>
```